# Using when/alternatives inside when

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

I need to validate a schema with `joi`.

The object is like this:

1. There is a required property named "type" whose values can be `TYPE1`, `TYPE2`, `TYPE3`.
2. If `type === 'TYPE1'`, we must expect properties `one`, `two` and `three` at the same level.
3. If `type === 'TYPE2'`, we must expect properties `four`, `five` and `six` at the same level.
4. If `type === 'TYPE3'`, we must expect a `subtype` property at the same level, with possible values `A` and `B`.

   - If `subtype === 'A'`, then we must expect properties `seven`, `eight`, `nine` at the same level.
   - If `subtype === 'B'`, then we must expect properties `ten`, `eleven`, `twelve` at the same level.

This is what I came up with:

```js
import { object, string, validate } from 'joi';

const obj1 = { // valid
  type: 'TYPE1',
  one: '01',
  two: '02',
  three: '03',
};
const obj2 = { // valid
  type: 'TYPE2',
  four: '04',
  five: '05',
  six: '06',
};
const obj3 = { // valid
  type: 'TYPE3',
  subtype: 'A',
  seven: '07',
  eight: '08',
  nine: '09',
};
const obj4 = { // valid
  type: 'TYPE3',
  subtype: 'B',
  ten: '10',
  eleven: '11',
  twelve: '12',
};

const joiSchema = object({
  // point 1
  type: string().valid('TYPE1', 'TYPE2', 'TYPE3').required(),
})
.when(
  // point 2
  object({ type: 'TYPE1' }).unknown(),
  {
    then: object({
      one: string().required(),
      two: string().required(),
      three: string().required(),
    }),
  },
)
.when(
  // point 3
  object({ type: 'TYPE2' }).unknown(),
  {
    then: object({
      four: string().required(),
      five: string().required(),
      six: string().required(),
    }),
  },
)
.when(
  // point 4
  object({ type: 'TYPE3' }).unknown(),
  {
    then: object(
      // if type === 'TYPE3', check for one of those schemas
      {
        // point 4
        subtype: string().valid('A', 'B'),
      },
    ).when(
      // point 4.1
      object({ subtype: 'A' }).unknown(),
      {
        then: object({
          seven: string().required(),
          eight: string().required(),
          nine: string().required(),
        }),
      },
    ).when(
      // point 4.2
      object({ subtype: 'B' }).unknown(),
      {
        then: object({
          ten: string().required(),
          eleven: string().required(),
          twelve: string().required(),
        }),
      },
    ),
  },
);

const result1 = validate(obj1, joiSchema);
console.log('Validating obj1')
if (result1.error) {
  console.error(result1.error.message);
}

const result2 = validate(obj2, joiSchema);
console.log('Validating obj2')
if (result2.error) {
  console.error(result2.error.message);
}

const result3 = validate(obj3, joiSchema);
console.log('Validating obj3')
if (result3.error) {
  console.error(result3.error.message);
}

const result4 = validate(obj4, joiSchema);
console.log('Validating obj4')
if (result4.error) {
  console.error(result4.error.message);
}
```

This snippet is available for testing here: https://repl.it/@AlessandroDe5/Joi-MCVE

It is showing this error:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot merge type object with another type: alternatives
    at new AssertionError (internal/errors.js:315:11)
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/runner/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:559:11)
    at internals.Object.concat (/home/runner/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:148:14)
    at internals.Alternatives.when (/home/runner/node_modules/joi/lib/types/alternatives/index.js:131:52)
    at index.ts:52:6
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:65:33)
    at startRepl (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/bin.ts:157:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/bin.ts:66:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
```

If I remove the nested `when` (point 4, 4.1, 4.2) it works without errors and of course rejects the last two objects.

I also tried replacing `when` with `alternatives`:

```js
.when(
  // point 4
  object({ type: 'TYPE3' }).unknown(),
  {
    then: alternatives().try(
      object({
        subtype: string().valid('A'),
        seven: string().required(),
        eight: string().required(),
        nine: string().required(),
      }),
    ).when(
      object({
        subtype: string().valid('B'),
        ten: string().required(),
        eleven: string().required(),
        twelve: string().required(),
      }),
    ),
  },
);
```

As one could expect I get the exact same error.

Is there a way accomplish the task somehow?

Comment: Did you check this github issue already? https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1021 It sounds quite similar to your issue. It's quite weird that the error is thrown at line 52, though.

Comment: @briosheje Yes, I looked at that issue, unfortunately they say to use `when/is/then/otherwise` which is limiting because I can only have two branches (`then`, `otherwise`). My MCVE is simplified, my real scenario is about 10 different schemas which differ based on the `subtype`, so I can't use this solution here. Maybe I could chain `when`/`otherwise` to reproduce an `if`/`else if` scenario, but this seems ugly. Is this the only solution?

Comment: Not sure, I've personally never used joi before. Perhaps someone else have other ideas. Otherwise, you may want to open another issue or reopen the existing one, maybe the author or the team may give you further help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach by using **Joi.alternatives()**, this way you can avoid nested **when**, so your schema should look like this:

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid('TYPE1').required(),
        one: Joi.string().required(),
        two: Joi.string().required(),
        three: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
    Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid('TYPE2').required(),
        four: Joi.string().required(),
        five: Joi.string().required(),
        six: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
    Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid('TYPE3').required(),
        subtype: Joi.string().valid('A', 'B')
    })
        .when(Joi.object({ subtype: 'A' }).unknown(), {
            then: Joi.object({
                seven: Joi.string().required(),
                eight: Joi.string().required(),
                nine: Joi.string().required(),
            }),
        })
        .when(Joi.object({ subtype: 'B' }).unknown(), {
            then: Joi.object({
                ten: Joi.string().required(),
                eleven: Joi.string().required(),
                twelve: Joi.string().required(),
            }),
        }),
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as said in comments I have way more properties and possible values than shown in the question (I made a short example just to demonstrate the issue, my real scenario is bigger), so this would result in a lot of unnecessary repetitions. I ended up abandoning joi in favor or ajv, which support validation against JSON-Schema draft 07 (which supports nested when clauses and is way more readable than Joi's js schema). Thanks a lot though!

Comment: No problem! but yeah, I agree, Joi may not be the right option for complicated schemas.